# The proxy server is refusing connections on my windows P.C

Tags: configuration, windows, firefox, proxy, connection

My Computer is a PC, not a MAC.  But I cannot connect to the Onion sites. Whenever I try, i get the following message:

The proxy server is refusing connections

Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.

```
Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.
```

Is the problem Firefox?  Is it the Proxy settings? What am I supposed to change?

Comment: I’m not sure anyone can say without more detail. Can you post the settings you’re using in Firefox? And how are you setting up the Tor proxy (what settings have you set in your torrc)? Finally are you sure the tor process is running and is listening for SOCKS connections?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers I read worked, so after playing with the problem and being extremely frustrated,

**I went to "*add ons*" and I added and enabled the "Torbutton 2.1.13"**

and it worked! Yippee, goddammit! What an f'en waste of time!
And make sure Manual proxy config is checked with 127.0.0.1 as SOCKS Host Port 9150,
No Proxy for: localhost, 127.0.01
Then make sure your Firefox proxy is auto detect proxy. Tor seems to work in concert with Firefox's settings it seems.

IT WOULD BE SO BENEFICIAL IF WHEN A NEW UPDATE COMES OUT TECH SUPPORT WOULD UPDATE TROUBLESHOOTING POSSIBILITIES! It is such a waste of time to work for hours or days on problems which should have easy to find solutions. Everything I found was many months to years old. And there was just a Tor update this month!